# Julia get stuck when pushing into two arrays

Tags: julia

I am not sure why but when I try to use `push!` two times (to append values in two different arrays), julia gets stuck. I have tried commenting out one of the `push!` lines and it executes fine. But with both it just doesn't work.

Any ideas why this maybe?

[image]

```
print(candidates)
# organisation is a similar array
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the inner loop. Also, you are using the variable `can` and `org` in an ambiguous way.

```
can = []
org = []

for (c, o) in zip(candidates, organisations)
   push!(can, c)
   push!(org, o)
   
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out the error. `vcat((split.(df.Name, "-"))...)` # Out > 87 element vector. `organisation = vcat(split.(df.Organisation, "-")...)` # Out > 88 element vector

Comment: Not sure how your data is organised/your objective, but consider also the difference between `push!` and `append!`: `dest = []; push!(dest, ["a","b"]); #adds the vector a,b`
`append!(dest, ["c","d"]) # adds the individual elements`